# BLE on Android - Get UUID of nearby devices

Tags: android, kotlin, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

I am creating an app that through a ble scan returns a list of nearby devices, each device is an object which contains two pieces of information:

- UUID : String,
- rssi: Int

I can get the rssi value and device address but I can't figure out how to get the uuid.
I can't find explanations on the basic code to implement and most of the answers are on Java code, which is not very easy to adapt into kotlin, at least for me.

I tried this way, but I don't know if I'm doing it right or if I'm completely off track for what I would like to achieve

Scan Settings:

```
private val scanSettings = ScanSettings.Builder()
        .setScanMode(ScanSettings.SCAN_MODE_LOW_LATENCY)
        .build()`
```

Scan Callback

```
private val scanCallback = object : ScanCallback() {
        @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
        override fun onScanResult(callbackType: Int, result: ScanResult) {

            val listUUID = result.scanRecord?.serviceUuids
            if(listUUID != null){
                val parcelUuid =  listUUID[0]
                val device = Device(devUUID = parcelUuid.uuid.toString(), rssi = result.rssi)
                listDevice.add(device)
            }

        override fun onScanFailed(errorCode: Int) {
            Log.e("ScanCallback", "onScanFailed: code $errorCode")
        }
    }
```

To start the scan
`bleScan.startScan(null, scanSettings, scanCallback)`

Comment: Have you requested the necessary Bluetooth permissions? Note that there are different permissions for device up to Android 12 and and Android 12+.

Comment: Yes, for Android 11 or lower devices I request permissions to access the coarse and fine location, for Android 12+ I add Bluetooth connection and scan permissions

Comment: Are aware that not all Bluetooth device advertisements contain service IDs? I would instead display the device name and Bluetooth address for showing a list of devices.

Comment: I know, but it's not up to me, what was asked of me is to create the list of Device objects, which must contain the uuid and the rssi. Unfortunately what worries me is whether the code I use is right or not to obtain the result I expressed in the question.

Comment: Rereading your question again I get the feeling that whoever gave you the task had something different in mind but expressed it wrong. May be because the person had iOS experience where the OS does not allow you to access device BT addresses and instead maps them to an UUID AFAIR. The service UUIDs you want to use do not identify a device. These are constants describing which services a device provides. Saving them doesn't make any sense to me as they are not identify a device. So I would suggest to talk to whoever defined the task and try to understand what you actually should do.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation, now I have a clearer idea of ​​the problem I had with the functioning of the application, I will raise the issue with my referent